# Service Class in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth-lowenergy

What is the purpose with Service class?

Many examples with Bluetooth Low Energy uses Service classes for all Bluetooth communication, connecting, disconnecting, scanning for devices etc. Activity classes always call method from this Service class.

What about implementing all Bluetooth communication directly in an Activity class instead?. Why does nobody implement like that and uses a Service class instead?

Comment: if you do communication in the main activity thread then it will block the UI taking the app to a non responding state.

Comment: Do not put "?.". It's either question "?" or declarative sentence ".". Never both.

Comment: Interested to know where these examples with Bluetooth Low Energy are as Android has no support for it properly yet.  Do you really mean standard Bluetooth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

Basically it is a loosly coupled component independet from activitys lifecylce. The problem is in Android you can't really control when an activity will be created/destroyed, so for example if you are loading somenthing in an activity and you receive a call, your activity might get destroyed and the result of your update will be lost, or even worst your loading task won't finish and holds on to the activity and it can't be garbage collected and you create a memory leak.

So you use service for long running background tasks, but you just let them run as long as you have to, to avoid, again, memory leaks and be nice to your resources.

> Caution: It's important that your application stops its services when it's done working, to avoid wasting system resources and consuming battery power. If necessary, other components can stop the service by calling stopService(). Even if you enable binding for the service, you must always stop the service yourself if it ever received a call to onStartCommand().

Comment: Can multiple services run parallelly?

Answer (score 1):

> what about implementing all Bluetooth communication directly in an Activity class instead

you most likely end being killed by the framework for doing too much on UI thread (aka ANR - Application Not Responding). See [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) article on develoer site.

Anything that is not directly related to UI (like networking of any kind) should be offloaded to separate task. Be it [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> This class allows to perform background operations and publish results
>   on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

or [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand.

. The [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) (not IntentService) is for slightly different purpose:

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.

Comment: IntentService is just a default implementation of the Service, it's the same pattern.

Comment: Intent service is being terminated when it's done - and that's the main difference

Comment: But that IS the pattern, a service should terminate itself when it isn't needed, IntentService provides a basic worker service for this purpose, if you a implementing it yourself, you just have to take care of it yourself to stop it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Service class is used to perform , background non UI operations like playing audio file.Further service is the component that will run in background even  if your activity gets destroyed ,While using Bluetooth we really do some non UI phone level operation and hence we use Services .

Answer (score 0):

Activity class isn't a good place for any kind of communication tasks. It can be killed as soon as user switches to another activity. It shows UI, that means that we can't do much work in Activity's thread. Sometimes you can use somthing like

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something here
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

or more complicated things with AsyncTask but this is suitable for short-time actions.

[Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) will not be killed so fast, so it's good for background work of any kind. Just read [Android documentation about services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: You should use Handlers or Asynctask and not Threads by itself in Android